# Proper way of re-using and closing a subprocess object

Tags: python, subprocess

I have the following code in a loop:

```
while true:
    # Define shell_command
    p1 = Popen(shell_command, shell=shell_type, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, preexec_fn=os.setsid)
    result = p1.stdout.read(); 
    # Define condition
    if condition:
       break;
```

**where `shell_command` is something like `ls`** (it just prints stuff).

I have read in different places that I can close/terminate/exit a `Popen` object in a variety of ways, e.g. :

```
p1.stdout.close()
p1.stdin.close()
p1.terminate
p1.kill
```

My question is:

1. What is the proper way of closing a `subprocess` object once we are done using it?
2. Considering the nature of my script, is there a way to open a `subprocess` object only once and reuse it with different shell commands? Would that be more efficient in any way than opening new `subprocess` objects each time?

### Update

I am still a bit confused about the sequence of steps to follow depending on whether I use `p1.communicate()` or `p1.stdout.read()` to interact with my process.

From what I understood in the answers and the comments:

If I use  `p1.communicate()` I don't have to worry about releasing resources, since `communicate()` would wait until the process is finished, grab the output and properly close the `subprocess` object

If I follow the `p1.stdout.read()` route (which I think fits my situation, since the shell command is just supposed to print stuff) I should call things in this order:

1. `p1.wait()`
2. `p1.stdout.read()`
3. `p1.terminate()`

Is that right?

Comment: `p1.stdout.close()` shouldn't close the process. Do you mean `p1.stdin.close()`? This also doesn't necessarily terminate the process, but it could cause that behaviour if the command is reading from STDIN.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> What is the proper way of closing a subprocess object once we are done using it?

`stdout.close()` and `stdin.close()` will not terminate a process *unless* it exits itself on end of input or on write errors.

[`.terminate()`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.terminate) and [`.kill()`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.kill) both do the job, with `kill` being a bit more "drastic" on POSIX systems, as `SIGKILL` is sent, which cannot be ignored by the application. Specific differences are explained [in this blog post](http://rackerhacker.com/2010/03/18/sigterm-vs-sigkill/), for example. On Windows, there's no difference.

Also, remember to [`.wait()`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait) and to close the pipes after killing a process to avoid zombies and force the freeing of resources.

A special case that is often encountered are processes which read from STDIN and write their result to STDOUT, closing themselves when EOF is encountered. With these kinds of programs, it's often sensible to use [`subprocess.communicate`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate):

```
>>> p = Popen(["sort"], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
>>> p.communicate("4\n3\n1")
('1\n3\n4\n', None)
>>> p.returncode
0
```

This can also be used for programs which print something and exit right after:

```
>>> p = Popen(["ls", "/home/niklas/test"], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
>>> p.communicate()
('file1\nfile2\n', None)
>>> p.returncode
0
```

> Considering the nature of my script, is there a way to open a subprocess object only once and reuse it with different shell commands? Would that be more efficient in any way than opening new subprocess objects each time?

I don't think the `subprocess` module supports this and I don't see what resources could be shared here, so I don't think it would give you a significant advantage.

Comment: In your code you called `communicate()`, but didn't call `terminate()` nor `kill()`. Does `communicate()` always properly close and free resources?

Comment: @roseck: I thought a link to the docs would be enough. Quote: "Wait for process to terminate."

Comment: @roseck: `communicate()` only makes sense when the child process is controlled via I/O (i.e. it must exit when the input channel is closed)

Comment: @AaronDigulla: You're absolutely right, I was almost sure I had mentioned it, but I was mistaken :)

Comment: Thanks @AaronDigulla, I presume that from your comment using `communicate()` does not make sense in the example I posted since my shell command does not take anything from `stdin`, it just prints stuff (e.g. like `ls`). Is that right? Either way, from what I understand if I use `communicate()` I don't have to do anything else to release resources, but if I use `stdout.read()` I should do things in this order `Popen` `wait()` `read()` `terminate()`. Is that correct?

Comment: @roseck: Most shell commands use I/O to control their life times - in these cases `communicate()` is the way to go because it solves everything in a single line of code. For more complex processes, you need to know how said process behaves: How do you talk to it? What does it do/expect? There is no general solution anymore. Please create a new question with more details about the executable that you want to control.

Comment: @roseck: I added another example with `ls` using `communicate`. If you don't want to use that for some reason (though you really should), you could do `p.wait()` to wait for `ls` to exit itself and then `p.stdout.read()`. If you need to terminate the sub process for some reason, you have to do that *before* `wait()`ing, obviously.

Comment: @NiklasB.: `p.stdout.read()` should go before `p.wait()`. Otherwise a deadlock might occur if the program produces enough output e.g., ~65K on Linux. If input/output are bounded `.communicate()` should be used instead.

Comment: It is not pointless to close `p.stdout`. `p.stdin/p.stdout/p.stderr` should be closed to avoid leaking resources.

Comment: @J.F. Sebastion: Right, I should add that, but usually it shouldn't be a good way to terminate a process.

Comment: @Niklas B.: I don't see where I suggested to terminate a process.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: In his question, OP suggested that calling `p.stdout.close()` would be a way to terminate the process. This is the assumption I referred to in my answer and last comment.

Comment: @Niklas B.: If it is not clear I can say explicitly: `p.stdin/p.stdout/p.stderr` should be closed to avoid leaking resources such as file descriptors. `p.stdout.close()` *might* lead to a process termination (via Broken pipe error) but such usage is not recommended.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Yes, I know that, and I already added that to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

> Considering the nature of my script, is there a way to open a subprocess object only once and reuse it with different shell commands?

Yes.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import print_function
import uuid
import random
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

MARKER = str(uuid.uuid4())

shell_command = 'echo a'
p = Popen('sh', stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT,
          universal_newlines=True) # decode output as utf-8, newline is '\n'
while True:
    # write next command
    print(shell_command, file=p.stdin)
    # insert MARKER into stdout to separate output from different shell_command
    print("echo '%s'" % MARKER, file=p.stdin)
    # read command output
    for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, MARKER+'\n'):
        if line.endswith(MARKER+'\n'):
            print(line[:-len(MARKER)-1])
            break # command output ended without a newline
        print(line, end='')
    # exit on condition
    if random.random() < 0.1:
        break
# cleanup
p.stdout.close()
if p.stderr:
   p.stderr.close()
p.stdin.close()
p.wait()
```

Put `while True` inside `try: ... finally:` to perform the cleanup in case of exceptions. On Python 3.2+ you could use `with Popen(...):` instead.

> Would that be more efficient in any way than opening new subprocess objects each time?

Does it matter in your case? Don't guess. Measure it.

Answer (score 2):

The "correct" order is:

1. Create a thread to read stdout (and a second one to read stderr, unless you merged them into one).
2. Write commands to be executed by the child to stdin. If you're not reading stdout at the same time, writing to stdin can block.
3. Close stdin (this is the signal for the child that it can now terminate by itself whenever it is done)
4. When stdout returns EOF, the child has terminated. Note that you need to synchronize the stdout reader thread and your main thread.
5. call `wait()` to see if there was a problem and to clean up the child process

If you need to stop the child process for any reason (maybe the user wants to quit), then you can:

1. Close stdin if the child terminates when it reads EOF.
2. Kill the with `terminate()`. This is the correct solution for child processes which ignore stdin.
3. If the child doesn't respond, try `kill()`

In all three cases, you must call `wait()` to clean up the dead child process.

Answer (score 1):

1. Depends on what you expect the process to do; you should always call `p1.wait()` in order to avoid zombies. Other steps depend on the behaviour of the subprocess; if it produces any output, you should consume the output (e.g. `p1.read()` ...but this would eat lots of memory) and only then call the `p1.wait()`; or you may wait for some timeout and call `p1.terminate()` to kill the process if you think it doesn't work as expected, and possible call `p1.wait()` to clean the zombie.

Alternatively, `p1.communicate(...)` would do the handling if io and waiting for you (not the killing).

1. Subprocess objects aren't supposed to be reused.